# How to use distinct in group by query?

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, min

I have this query

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    played_level, 
    sum( time_taken ) AS time_take
FROM answer
WHERE completed =1
GROUP BY played_level, user_id
ORDER BY time_take
LIMIT 20
```

This query shows all user id who took minimum time.

But now I want to display only distict user id with his minimum time.

```
 user_id    played_level    time_take   
     1      18                19
     1      12                21
     2       3                25
     6       3                26
     2       2                27
     6       4                27
     1       8                32
```

expected output:

```
user_id  played_level time_taken
 1         18          19
 2          3          25
 6          3          26
```

Comment: If you want to measure min time on each level, you can't show user id as distinct on result.

Comment: Are there any duplicates when on `user_id`, `played_level`? Because in your data combination of (`user_id`, `played_level`) seems to be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First select all distict user_id from table

```
                $distinct_users = "SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM answer where addeddate BETWEEN :currdate1 AND :currdate2 AND completed=1";
                $distinct_users_data = $conn->prepare($distinct_users);
                $distinct_users_data->execute(array(':currdate1'=>$prev_date,':currdate2'=>$currdate2));
                $distinct_users_arr = $distinct_users_data->fetchAll();
```

Now find the minimum time of this user_id and store it in array

```
                foreach($distinct_users_arr as $distict_data)
                    {
                    $user_ids=$distict_data['user_id'];


                $all_user_time = "SELECT user_id, played_level, sum( time_taken ) AS time_take FROM answer where addeddate BETWEEN :currdate1 AND :currdate2 
                                  AND completed=1 AND user_id=:user_id GROUP BY played_level, user_id ORDER BY time_take limit 1";
                $all_user_time_data = $conn->prepare($all_user_time);
                $all_user_time_data->execute(array(':currdate1'=>$prev_date,':currdate2'=>$currdate2,':user_id'=>$user_ids));
                $all_user_time_arr = $all_user_time_data->fetchAll();
                $all_count= $all_user_time_data->rowCount();
                foreach($all_user_time_arr as $leading_user)
                            {
                            $new_user_id= $leading_user['user_id'];
                            $new_time= $leading_user['time_take'];

                                $leader_board[] = array(
                                                'user_id'=>$new_user_id, 
                                                'time_taken'=>$new_time
                                            );

                            }


                    }
```

At end sort that array order by time taken. We get final result

```
foreach ($leader_board as $key => $row) 
                                         {
                                    $sorting[$key] = $row['time_taken'];
                                        }
                            array_multisort($sorting, SORT_ASC, $leader_board);
```

Answer (score 2):

ALthough you can do this with a `join`, that is complicated because you have to repeat the aggregation.  You can also do this with nested aggregations.  The hard part is getting the `played_level` where the minimum occurs.  The following query uses a trick to get that using `substring_index()`/`group_concat()`.  Here is the query without the `limit` clause -- I'm not quite sure what you want to limit:

```
select user_id,
       substring_index(group_concat(played_level order by time_take), ',', 1) as played_level,
       min(time_take) as time_take
from (SELECT user_id, played_level, sum( time_taken ) AS time_take
      FROM answer
      WHERE completed =1
      GROUP BY played_level, user_id
     ) a
group by user_id
ORDER BY time_take;
```

Answer (score 0):

To `SELECT DISTINCT`

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT user_id, 
    played_level, 
    sum( time_taken ) AS time_take
FROM answer
WHERE completed =1
GROUP BY played_level
ORDER BY time_take
LIMIT 20
```

You can also make use of the `GROUP BY` for that like this.

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    played_level, 
    sum( time_taken ) AS time_take
FROM answer
WHERE completed =1
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY time_take
LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant something like: you wanted last level which is finished by each user:

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    max(played_level) current user_level, 
    sum(time_taken) AS time_take
FROM answer
WHERE completed =1
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY time_take 
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: So how do you want to get distinct values? If `user11 finished `level` and `level2` faster than all, you want to just return one of his/her records?

Comment: I just want single user id whose time is minumum.

Comment: And you want to display the time too? Which time? `level1` or `level2`?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use subquery then in this case

```
select
 user_id, 
    played_level, 
    min( time_taken ) AS time_take
from(
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    max(played_level) played_level, 
    sum( time_taken ) AS time_take
FROM answer
WHERE completed =1
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY time_take
LIMIT 20 
) a
group by user_id
```

Comment: min time taken may not match the played level in the outer query.

Comment: @krishna Your query showing one record. I want to show all records

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
        user_id, 
        played_level, 
        SUM(time_taken) AS time_take
    FROM answer
    WHERE completed = 1
    GROUP BY played_level, user_id
) x INNER JOIN (
    SELECT played_level, user_id, MIN(time_take) AS mn
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            user_id, 
            played_level, 
            SUM(time_taken) AS time_take
        FROM answer
        WHERE completed = 1
        GROUP BY played_level, user_id
    ) y
    GROUP BY user_id, played_level
) z ON x.user_id = z.user_id
    AND x.played_level = z.played_level AND x.time_take = z.mn
```

inline view `z` has `MIN(time_take)` for each (user_id, played_level), finally joined with your original query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a JOIN via subquery:

```
SELECT user_id, played_level, time_taken
FROM answer
JOIN (
   SELECT user_id AS t_user_id, MIN(time_taken) AS min_time_taken
   FROM answer
   GROUP BY user_id
) t
ON answer.user_id = t.t_user_id AND answer.time_taken = t.min_time_taken
WHERE completed = 1
ORDER BY time_take
LIMIT 20
```